# vertices run wild during bevel

Tags: vertices, bevel

As near as I can tell, there is only one vertex in this corner, but when I try to bevel the edge it seems to let go and run wild.  What can I do to make it stay put during the bevel?

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2):

You have overlapping vertices and edges in your example.

The easiest way to fix this would be to select every vertex in your mesh, press <kbd>m</kbd>, and then select `merge by distance`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was able to get rid of 4 vertices doing that.  I kept increasing the distance until it started messing everything up.  Unfortunately, the bevel still has this behavior.

Comment: If you upload your .blend I (or others) can definitely figure this out for you.

Comment: Here's the blend https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NsYejv7-pvo9Ek07T7C31y_vxvfm12Ag/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I used the Construction Lines add-on to create the lettering.  My attempts to import an SVG from Inkscape were too messy.  My goal here is to round/bevel the edges about 0.05m and apply a rock texture look using a rock brush and texturing technique I was watching here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8dZl8uheKA&t=659s

When finished, I want to save it as a Collada and import it into Second Life.